# Heatmap clustering/dendrogram values/colours

Tags: r, graph, plot, data.table

I've created a heatmap and clustered using the dendrograms to get the following result:

[image]

The highlights that you see on the row dendrograms is essentially what I'm looking to distinguish. I require a way to get the values of those specific lines or find a way to getting all the row names associated with those lines. Or, would it be possible to set a specific colour to each of those lines. I'm not aware of any ways of doing either.

The reason for this is that I'm creating a scatterplot in correlation with the heatmap. Essentially, each row (name not included in the heatmap) will be a point on the scatterplot and each of the highlighted dendrogram clusters will be assigned a colour on the scatterplot. So, there will be 6 colours on the scatterplot belonging to the rows associated with each cluster.

Some examples as to what others are doing are as follows:

[image: Instead of colouring the dendrograms, this adds a bar]
Instead of colouring the dendrograms, this adds a bar

[image]
This adds the colours to the dendrogram itself

Currently, I'm making the heatmap like so:

```
hm <- heatmap.2(percentMatrix, scale="none",
cexRow=0.75, cexCol=1.0, key=TRUE, keysize=1.5,
margins=c(10,22),
trace="none")
```

I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

So it seemed after much tinkering, I've managed to figure it out. I can simply print hm to get the carpet and then parse out the order. I've added a rowcolorbar to the heatmap using cutree.

Answer (score 0):

you should look in these examples using "heatmap.2" and "annHeatmap2". In both pages describe a pretty examples as you want for.

- heatmap.2:
  http://www.molecularecologist.com/2013/08/making-heatmaps-with-r-for-microbiome-analysis/
- annHeatmap2:
  http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=Heatplus/man/annHeatmap2.Rd&d=R_BC

Regards,
Alex